# Brownian motion 'reset' at stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

This is probably a standard question, apologies for that in advance.

Let $(\Omega, {\cal F}, {\cal F}_t,\mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space on which a Wiener process $\{W(\omega,t)\}_{\omega \in \Omega, t \geq 0}$ can be modelled. The latter process is adapted to the filtration ${\cal F}_t$. Let $\tau:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^+$ be a stopping time. How does one precisely prove that the process $\{W_\tau(\omega,t)\}_{\omega \in \Omega, t \geq 0}$ defined by
$$W_\tau(\omega,t)=W(\omega,\,t+\tau(\omega))-W(\omega,\,\tau(\omega))$$
is again a Wiener process?

Comment: Did you check out the literature? You can find a proof for instance in *Brownian motion - An introduction to stochastic processes* by Schilling & Partzsch.

Comment: Can you specify a page/chapter?

Comment: Chapter 6, I think.